# jquery resize scrollbar to fit height of overlay div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to create something similar to this: http://tapiture.com/popular

not the site, but the onClick image event.
when you click an image, the scrollbar resizes to the height of the overlay image.

how can i make something like this using jquery?

Comment: Would be nice if you to could share what you done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When they open a modal, they add the following class to the body

```
   .modal-open {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
```

so with overflow hidden, all the images behind the modal are, well, hidden.
So the scrollbar adapts to the content of the modal.

On the modal layer, they added this class

```
.modal-scrollable {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Notice how overflow is at auto, that means that scrollbars will show if needed on that layer.

Comment: i did try to find a solution. i spent hours doing so, but for some reason i couldn't get the hang of it...seems like you are just too good as a programmer....i really appreciate your work...thanks again

Comment: Didn't want to disrespect you or anything but on Stackoverflow we get tons of questions "how to do this" and most didn't even try to find an answer. If you spend hours on something, next time, provide some code please. I updated the answer also.

Comment: No, i understand. No more excuses. I would have written some code, but i absolutely had no idea on how to start working on this feature.....All i had was just a start event once the image was clicked and it seemed irrelevant to include in the question, because this is just too simple. But i will reply and post the whole function once done

Answer (score 1):

As promised,here's the code i did.

JQuery:

```
    $('.item').on('click','img', function(){
        $this = $(this);
        $('body').addClass('modal_open');
        $('#overlay').fadeIn();
        $('#img_zoom').html('new and bigger image tag').fadeIn();
    });
```

CSS:

```
#overlay{z-index: 1; position: fixed; height: 100%; width:100%; background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3); display:none;}
#img_zoom{position: fixed; z-index: 2; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000; display:none; bottom: 0; left: 0; overflow: auto; right: 0; top: 0;}

.modal_open {overflow: hidden; position: relative; }
.modal_scrollable {bottom: 0; left: 0; overflow: auto; position: fixed; right: 0; top: 0; }
```

All thanks to **ComputerArts**